# Opaque Handle in C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing an opaque data structure that is internally an array of opaque data structures. Let's call them records. There will be multiple queries to different fields of a record each with the same key. I have a list of APIs of this form:

```
QueryFieldX(KEY key, FieldX& Data)
```

Each query currently searches through the records with the key and then gets the Data.

I want to change it to the following form:

```
GetHandleToRecord(KEY key, MYHANDLE handle);
QueryFieldX(MYHANDLE handle, FieldX& Data);
```

The advantage is that searching every single time through the records is eliminated. I can implement a MYHANDLE myself but I want to know if there is a good library / data structure / primitive in C++ that gives me an opaque handle that I can use.

Comment: I want the Record to be opaque as well. Updated the question

Comment: Return the array index, and supply that to the query function?

Comment: The data structure may not be an array in future. It may be a tree or may be a hash with the handle being the key itself.

Comment: And you don't want to use a pointer in case someone tries to dereference it directly?

Comment: Yes that is the reason. I thought if there could be something like handle = Encrypt(ptr) and ptr = decrypt(handle) in the called code it would solve my purposes. I can have a wrapper around the ptr and make it private and that should be enough I think. But is there a better or well-known way ?

Answer (score 1):

A handle is typically an obfuscated pointer to the data, such as this.

```
typedef void* MYHANDLE;
```

You would explicitly `reinterpret_cast` the pointer as needed, such as in this code.

```
MYHANDLE GetHandleToRecord(KEY key)
{
   FieldX *the_result;

   // (assign the correct pointer to the_result)

   return reinterpret_cast<MYHANDLE>( the_result );
}

QueryFieldX(MYHANDLE handle, FieldX& Data)
{
    Data = *reinterpret_cast<FieldX*>( handle )
}
```

In your case, the handle could also be an array index, or a key to a `std::map`.  Anything that can later be converted back to the data itself.

Comment: If I understand correctly, he wants a handle which cannot be used to directly access the data (rules out pointers), and which is not container-dependent (rules out array index or std::map key).